# PhpUnit test - Non-mocked method does not exist

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I got a problem with call public method. There is a simple example:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar()
    {
        return array();
    }
}

//test code
$test = $this->getMock('Foo', array('____'));
var_dump($test instanceof Foo);
var_dump(method_exists($test, 'bar'));
$result = $test->bar();
```

And I got following result:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_Foo_abdf1ea1::bar()
```

Comment: array('____') - added to avoid total mocking.

Comment: Probably the Foo class is not loaded when setting the mockup, so a dummy class is created.

Comment: The problem is what @gontrollez mentions.  If I create a file with the class and the test together, there is no problem.  You have a problem with autoloading and the class is not available.  So PHPUnit doesn't know that the class has the method `bar`

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! It's so simply.)))

Answer (score 0):

The problem in autoloading as guys mentioned above (my bootstrap.php didn't load).
So class has been created but not from real class.
I got an error on line:

```
new Foo();
```

So in such case I think it's the best way to check class loading.